# Querying by MongoDB ISODate in Clojure (monger/clj-time)

Tags: mongodb, clojure, monger

**Disclaimer: Clojure noob.**

I'm trying to implement a simple `get-shows` function to return upcoming shows from a MongoDB instance. This returns a `LazySeq` of length 3, which is what I'd expect:

```
(defn get-shows []
  (let [date-str (f/unparse (f/formatters :basic-date-time) (t/now))]
    (mc/find-maps db "shows")))
```

But when I add a filter argument to the query, it returns an empty `LazySeq`:

```
(defn get-shows []
  (let [date-str (f/unparse (f/formatters :basic-date-time) (t/now))]
    (mc/find-maps db "shows" {:date-time { $gte {$isoDate date-str} } })))
```

Am I using the wrong date format? Do I need to cast `date-str` as an `ISODate` in some other way?

I'm totally okay with storing/querying raw timestamps instead, especially if that simplifies the query, but I'm not sure how to do that in `clj-time`...

Answer (score 0):

You have probably solved this already, but did you try something like this:

```
(defn get-shows []
  (let [date (java.util.Date.)]
    (mc/find-maps db "shows" {:date-time {"$gte" date}})))
```